# $f:\mathbf{R}^n \to \mathbf{R}$'s derivative in each argument has the same sign everywhere. What is $f$'s shape?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, geometry, differential-geometry, convex-analysis

We have a differentiable $f:\mathbf{R}^n \to \mathbf{R}$ with the property that each partial derivative has the same sign everywhere in its domain.

Does this mean that the sublevel sets of $f$ (sets of the form $\{x|f(x)\leq \alpha\}$) are convex? I think yes; we can't have any 'waviness'

Comment: What do you mean by quasi-linear?

Comment: All sublevel and superlevel ($\{x| f(x)\leq \alpha \},\{x| f(x)\geq \alpha\}$) sets are convex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

For a counterexample let $f(x,y) = x - 2^y$ and $\alpha = 0$. The partial derivative w.r.t. $x$ is positive everywhere, the one w.r.t. $y$ is negative everywhere. However, the sublevel set $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid x - 2^y \leq 0\}$ is not convex, since it contains both of the points $(0,-3)$ and $(2,1)$ but not their midpoint $(1,-1)$.